# Mule expression language json substring

Tags: mule

I have a json payload and I'm trying to log a substring of the the json value:

Example json:

`{  "color":"red",
    "value":"#f00"
 }`

In my xml:

```
  <logger message="print substring of value: #[json:color] level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

This will log red, but what I want is just "re"
The following did not work, but I wanted something like this:

`<logger message="print substring of value: #[json:color].substring(0,1) level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do like this

```
    <set-variable variableName="extractColor" value="#[json:color]" doc:name="Variable"/>

    <set-payload value="#[(flowVars.extractColor).substring(0,2) ]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

or in data weave

```
         color: payload.color[0..2]
```

or use transformer to convert in to object and then you can do whatever is needed

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>

<set-variable variableName="extractColor" value="#[message.payload.color.substring(0,2)]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the third option.